# Use of conditional if together with '>' or '<' in variables in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to use the conditional if in conjunction with the operators **'>' or '<' on variables** with numeric values, as shown in the code

```
var list = [
  '0',182,
  '1',500,
  '2',443
];
var dic = ee.Dictionary(list)


var ze = ee.Algorithms.If(dic.contains('0'),ee.Number(dic.get('0')),0);
var on = ee.Algorithms.If(dic.contains('1'),ee.Number(dic.get('1')),0);
var tw = ee.Algorithms.If(dic.contains('2'),ee.Number(dic.get('2')),0);
var thr = ee.Algorithms.If(dic.contains('3'),ee.Number(dic.get('3')),0);

var selec = ee.Algorithms.If(ze > thr, ze, thr)

print(selec)
```

However, by occupying the numbers stored in variables the if algorithm delivers the **false value**, which does not happen if the number is placed directly. I tried to use .gt but it only works for images. I need to do this with numbers stored in variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the result of `ee.Algorithms.If` to an `ee.Number` to use `ee.Number.gt`, for example.

```js
var list = [
  '0',182,
  '1',500,
  '2',443
];
var dic = ee.Dictionary(list)

var ze = ee.Number(ee.Algorithms.If(dic.contains('0'), dic.get('0'), 0));
var on = ee.Number(ee.Algorithms.If(dic.contains('1'), dic.get('1'), 0));
var tw = ee.Number(ee.Algorithms.If(dic.contains('2'), dic.get('2'), 0));
var thr = ee.Number(ee.Algorithms.If(dic.contains('3'), dic.get('3'), 0));

var selec = ee.Algorithms.If(ze.gt(thr), ze, thr)

print(selec)
```

However, [`ee.Algorithms.If` should be avoided](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#avoid-ee.algorithms.if) when there are alternative methods. In your case, you can use the `defaultValue` parameter of [`ee.Dictionary.get`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-dictionary-get) to set unavailable keys to a selected value.

```js
var ze = ee.Number(dic.get('0', 0));
var on = ee.Number(dic.get('1', 0));
var tw = ee.Number(dic.get('2', 0));
var thr = ee.Number(dic.get('3', 0));

var selec = ee.Algorithms.If(ze.gt(thr), ze, thr)

print(selec)
```